# Python's dir(object) and __builtin__ equivalent in Julia

Tags: julia, built-in

In Python, there's a [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#dir) and `__builtin__` list of built-in objects.

```
>>> dir(__builtins__)
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotImplemented', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'ReferenceError', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StandardError', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError', '_', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__import__', '__name__', '__package__', 'abs', 'all', 'any', 'apply', 'basestring', 'bin', 'bool', 'buffer', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'cmp', 'coerce', 'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'eval', 'execfile', 'exit', 'file', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'intern', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'long', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'raw_input', 'reduce', 'reload', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'unichr', 'unicode', 'vars', 'xrange', 'zip']
```

**Is there a `dir()` function that can probe objects in Julia?**

**Is there also a list of `__builtin__` objects in Julia?**

Comment: I have a macro I use for this.  it is based on the one I posted [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138246/saving-the-values-of-all-variabled-declared-in-a-block).
It's not quiet done, eg it ignores nested scopes.
I may fix that and release it as a package at some point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rough equivalents are:

- [names](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/base/?highlight=fieldnames#Base.names): returns bindings in a Module (optionally returns un-exported names with second argument `true`).
- [fieldnames](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/base/?highlight=fieldnames#Base.fieldnames): returns object field names.

> Is there also a list of **builtin** objects in Julia?

Start with `names(Base)` and `names(Core)`.

Comment: What about a list of functions? In python, `dir()` provides not just fields but also functions.  `names(CSV)` and `fieldnames(CSV)` don't do that in Julia.

Comment: Try `names(CSV, all=true)`, though it's a bit verbose, so you might want to start with something like: `filter(x->!startswith(String(x), "#"), names(CSV, all=true))`.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting "function names does not accept keyword arguments."  I'm on version 0.6.4, but the 0.6.4 docs say that names does accept `names(x::Module, all::Bool=false, imported::Bool=false)`

Comment: I agree it should.   I don't know why it gives the "function names does not accept keyword arguments" error.  I start the Julia REPL, type `names(Base, all = true)` and get the error.  `names(Base)` works fine.